# Python join list of dicts based on join conditon

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 list of dicts. I'd like to merge the dicts based on the below join condition.

**Input:**

```
List1: [{'id': 'value1', 'name': 'value2'}, {'id': 'value3', 'name': 'value4'}, {'id': 'value5', 'name': 'value2'}]

List2: [{'l2id': 'uuuu', 'l2name': 'value2'},{'l2id': 'zzzz', 'l2name': 'value4'}]
```

Join List1 and List2 if `List1.name == List2.l2name`

**Output list:**

```
[{'id': 'value1', 'name': 'value2', 'l2id': 'uuuu'},
 {'id': 'value3', 'name': 'value4', 'l2id': 'zzzz'},
 {'id': 'value5', 'name': 'value2', 'l2id': 'uuuu'}]
```

Comment: That is fairly simple. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Probably you want the keys to be `str`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for dct in List1:
    d[dct["name"]].append(dct)

result = [{**d1, **d2} for d2 in List2 for d1 in d[d2.pop("l2name")]]
# [{'id': 'value1', 'name': 'value2', 'l2id': 'uuuu'}, 
#  {'id': 'value5', 'name': 'value2', 'l2id': 'uuuu'}, 
#  {'id': 'value3', 'name': 'value4', 'l2id': 'zzzz'}]
```

Or, if you don't want to mutate the existing dicts:

```
result = [{**d1, "l2id": d2["l2id"]} for d2 in List2 for d1 in d[d2["l2name"]]]
```

Comment: The above solution is great. What's the best way to maintain this output + add remaining dicts in List1 that did not have a match in List2 based on the given condition?